# Something unknown with opening URL in Safari

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiwebview

guys. I'm trying to realize opening link from my webView in safari. Sometimes it works perfect, sometimes showing exc bad access.
This is my code:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    urlWillShow = [request mainDocumentURL];
    return YES;   
}
- (IBAction)openInSafari {
        NSLog(@"Will try to open in safari link: %@", [urlWillShow absoluteString]);
    if ([[urlWillShow scheme] isEqualToString:@"http"] || [[urlWillShow scheme] isEqualToString:@"https"]) {
        BOOL canLoad = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:urlWillShow];
        if (canLoad == YES) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:urlWillShow];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not enough info to debug. Which line has the problem?

Comment: Check whether you actually have a URL in urlWillShow during those "SOMETIMES" at which you get BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: Are you using ARC, or manual retain/release?

Comment: I have urlWillShow, because uiwebview will load in this view controller ever. I have only two lines, where editing urlWillShow: *.h NSURL *urlWillShow; and line, which is shown in my question

Answer (score 0):

Use [request URL] instead of [request mainDocumentURL]

Also, you need to retain (if not using ARC) urlWillShow as its likely being released before your action is called.

Alternatively, make the UIWebView an IBOutlet and instead of storing urlWillShow in an ivar, you can use [[self.webView request] URL] in your action method.

Comment: [request url] - another url. For example. I need this site: habr.ru, but [request url] will be another, because it contains ad, which is loading after site...